# waitForElementToBeRemoved is timing out when passed an element

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm trying to use `waitForElementToBeRemoved` with just an element but Jest is timing out. When I pass in a function, it works.

My understanding from this feature was that it should be able to take an element: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/460

I verified my app is using @testing-library/dom@7.8.0.

Here's the code:

```js
// doesn't work
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText("Loading..."));

// works
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByText("Loading..."));
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That is very strange, because I just had the opposite experience. I was passing a function, which was timing out, even though the rendering was quick. And then I made it the same as your "doesn't work" example and now it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I faced the same issue with **React Testing Library**, and the reason is the version of the library. By default `create-react-app` installing outdated version of `@testing-library`.
Here solution for **React Testing Library**:
Run CLI command `npm outdated` and check the versions of dependencies:

```
Package                      Current  Wanted  Latest
@testing-library/jest-dom      4.2.4   4.2.4  5.11.4
@testing-library/react         9.5.0   9.5.0  11.0.2
@testing-library/user-event    7.2.1   7.2.1  12.1.4
```

To update dependencies open `package.json` and manually update them to the latest:

```
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.4"
    ...
  },
  ...
```

Save changes and run CLI command: `npm install`

In case **DOM Testing Library** use the same steps for "@testing-library/dom"

Comment: Then you might run into the [MutationObserver is not a constructor](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/662). To fix it replace  `react-scripts` with  `react-scripts test --env=jsdom-fourteen` in the **package.json**

Answer (score 16):

And in addition to my previous answer, I would suggest to use `queryByText`:

```
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.queryByText("Loading..."));
```

rather than `getByText`:

```
await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText("Loading..."));
```

see [Common mistakes with React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-query-variants-for-anything-except-checking-for-non-existence)

Comment: Why? How is this query better suited than getByText?

Comment: When an query can be undefined then you should use `queryBy*`. In other cases where you are expecting an element use `getBy*`. So in conjunction with waitForElementToBeRemoved it's better to use `getBy*`. By the way, waitForElementToBeRemoved is not mentioned in that article.

Comment: What do you say about this: https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance Why they are using queryBy* as an example for waitForElementToBeRemoved? And in my previous answer I referred to: "Advice: Only use the query* variants for asserting that an element cannot be found." which exact the case for waitForElementToBeRemoved

Comment: `getBy*` already throws an error if it cannot find the element, making it more suitable to use `queryBy*` methods to return the element until null is returned when passed in to `waitForElementToBeRemoved()`